# Is POST the correct HTTP verb for resources that are produced by but not stored by the server?

Tags: http, crud, rest

Perhaps a partial duplicate of [What is the correct http verb for a Download in a REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57476169/what-is-the-correct-http-verb-for-a-download-in-a-rest-api) , though that is referring to a file download specifically.

In terms of CRUD operations, POST is the recommended HTTP verb for creating a resource. Does this still apply to creating resources, even if those resources are not persisted on the server? (i.e. stored in a database or similar) For example, generating some code based on code the client sent or converting a file and returning it to the client.

With such types of functionality, the server has indeed "created" something, though only in passing, returning or streaming it to the client, and not storing it in the traditional CRUD sense. I've always used POST for such functionality, but now I'm starting to double guess myself and think that those could have been GET endpoints the whole time.

Seems like a weird gray area in which neither HTTP verbs GET or POST completely match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is POST the correct HTTP verb for resources that are produced by but not stored by the server?

Yes - or alternatively, it's the least incorrect choice to use.

> POST serves many useful purposes in HTTP, including the general purpose of “this action isn’t worth standardizing.” -- [Fielding, 2009](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post)

In 2020, the HTTP-WG [adopted](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/ietf-http-wg/2020OctDec/0194.html) a proposal to define a method token for "GET with a body", which would give as an alternative to POST when we want to indicate to general purpose components that the request has safe semantics, so there should eventually be some [registered](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml) method that is a better fit.

Comment: Interesting... incidentally I've found a post that exactly summarizes this GET / POST conundrum: https://httptoolkit.tech/blog/http-search-method They as well in turn link to this SEARCH spec. What does the timeline look like for these proposals? I'd imagine for something like HTTP it takes years to actually update. HTTP/3 then maybe? :)

Comment: It has nothing to do with a specific HTTP version. When it is defined, it will apply to all of them (HTTP/1.*, HTTP/2, HTTP/3). How long it will take will mostly depend on the energy put into it. If you want to contibute, the internet draft contains all information you need.

Answer (score 1):

There is no gray area here.

If the state of the server changes, use an unsafe method like POST. If it does not, you can use a safe methof like GET, as long as you stay within the documented limitations of GET (no request body).

If you're looking for a safe method that does take a request body, you may want to look at https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-httpbis-safe-method-w-body/.

Comment: But there is absolutely nothing on the server that changes - this may be the case for any service that _does_ something with given inputs, but doesn't save or store anything during that process. So I'd argue here that the state of the server is _not_ changing.

Comment: Yes, that is right. So use GET if you can.